Construct ODE for a heat balloon valid at zero
A hot air balloon has volume $V \in [0, \infty]$ and total thermal energy $Q \in [0, \infty]$ of the air inside of the balloon.
At any moment in time, the balloon is either inflating or deflating with a known velocity $F(t)$, namely.
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = F(t)$$
If the balloon is deflating, its temperature does not change, so its thermal energy $Q$ is proportional to its volume $V$, and decreases, until eventually both volume and thermal energy are zero.
If the balloon is inflating, we know the temperature of its heat source $T_{in}(t)$, and the heat supplied to the balloon at any moment in time is
$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = C F(t) T_{in} (t)$$
where $C$ is the heat capacity of air (a constant). It is assumed that the temperature of the hot air balloon immediately averages out after inflow.
Question:
Is it possible to write a system of differential equations that fully cover the behaviour of the parameters ($V(t)$, $Q(t)$) of the air balloon given $F(t), T_{in}(t)$, and also behave as expected (i.e. do not blow up) when $V = 0$?
If you need to re-parameterize the model, please do so. If you need more than 2 state variables to accurately model this system, that's also ok.
